# DataGridRowStyle Overridden by RowHighlightBrush

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a DataGridStyle that modifies the Foreground property of its TextBlock based on a value called ApprovalLevel. It looks like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ApprovalLevel}" Value="-1">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ApprovalLevel}" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ApprovalLevel}" Value="1">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ApprovalLevel}" Value="2">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

This applies the style to the row without issue, however when the user highlights the row the style is overridden and the foreground colour is lost. I have tried applying styles such as:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

however all this does is override the entire row to be transparent. MY question is how can I make it clear to the user that they have selected a row whilst preserving the foreground style that I want to apply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Style the `TextBlock` using an `ElementStyle` instead of using a `DataGridRow` style:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dg">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="style" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ApprovalLevel}" Value="-1">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ApprovalLevel}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ApprovalLevel}" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ApprovalLevel}" Value="2">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding YourProperty}" ElementStyle="{StaticResource style}" />
        <!-- ... -->
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How would I go about modifying the HighlightedRowColour as this style seems to overwrite the method I was using before?

Comment: Please clarify your requirements. What colour do you want to change?